# SQL Server 2014 Express edition database growing beyond 10 GB limit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have a strange situation on a SQL Server 2014 Express edition server. The database reached 10 GB limit, but it continued to auto-grow the data file to a current size of 80 GB. There are a lot of auto-growing events.

I checked `sp_spaceused` and I have a few unallocated MB, also checked `sys.master_files`. In logs, I get the error:

> CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can the data file grow beyond 10 GB? What am I missing?

Comment: what was the sql query for first result set?

Comment: it's the result of executing sp_spaceused